# How to pass an argument to vuejs filters?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following vuejs filter

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.filter('truncate', function (value) {
   return value.substring(0, 10)
})
```

Which I then call as

```
<p> {{filename | truncate}} </p>
```

but I would like to pass the arguments `0`, `10` to the filter on the html. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This is straight up covered in the documentation. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try like this to pass extra value as param in vuejs filters

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#vue-instance",
    filters:{
      currency: function(value,arg1){
        return arg1+value;
      }
    },
    data: {
    },
    mounted() {
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.1/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-instance">
  {{123 | currency('$') }}
</div>
```

Docs says : [Filter-Argument-Syntax-changed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Filter-Argument-Syntax-changed)

In your given example

```js
Vue.filter('truncate', function (value,start,end) {
   return value.substring(start, end)
})

var app = new Vue({
    el: "#vue-instance",
    data: {
    },
    mounted() {
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.1/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-instance">
  {{ 'this is niklesh.raut' | truncate(0,10) }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html), filters are JavaScript functions, therefore they can take arguments, so you should be able to do:

```
<p> {{ filename | truncate(10) }} </p>
```

The value of filename will be passed into the first argument. 10 will be passed into `truncate` as its second argument

Answer (score 3):

Just extend and call your construction with parameters:

```
Vue.filter('truncate', function (value, from, count) {
  return value.substring(from, count)
})

<p>{{filename | truncate(0, 10)}}</p>
```